# SQL Server connection to db in network

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I developed an C# app that uses SQL Express initially the db and the app where located on the same machine.
The client now needs that the db can be available to another computer with the app installed, both are in the same network.
The 2 machines will share the same db. So computer 1 has the app and the db.  Computer 2 has the app and connects to the db located in the computer 1.
I tried to use the following connection string.

```
connectionString = "Data Source = 192.168.1.xx\SQLExpress,1433; Integrated Security=SSPI; Initial Catalog = dataBase;"/>
```

where the 192.168.1.xx is the IP from the computer 1.
The Tcp/Ip is enabled.
The firewall is disabled.
I installed the Sql Express in the second machine.
Is this enough to make the conection?
If I try to acess from computer 2 to the db I get an error “Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond”

Could  anyone  guide me with this?
I´m problably missing some steps or doing something wrong.

Comment: Please see this. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2005/05/05/415084.aspx. A bit old but may be relevant.

Comment: I followed this guide not too long ago; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345343(v=sql.100).aspx Worked for me

Comment: Please try this, http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48667/how-to-access-a-sql-server-database-from-other-computer-connected-to-the-same-wo

Comment: As you use "Integrated Security=SSPI" you might check if the Computer 2 or the related user has an access to the related database by looking at the Users below both Security and the Database sections.

Comment: Is the database *attached* to SQL Server Express? If you were previously using LocalDB, this was handled for you silently so you might not realize that you need to do this.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy ,yes the database is attached to SQL Server Express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I followed all the links that some members posted, with no joy, I changed the server authentication and used user and password to login, and it worked...
Thanks to all that tried to help.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe SSPI isn't available. Try `Integrated Security=True`.